# Filesystem errors when restoring many files

Tags: ext4, file-copy

I had an external hard drive that I mounted internally.  It came formatted with NTFS, and I wanted to move to ext4.  So I copied everything I wanted to keep onto other drives, created a brand new partition table (GPT) with a single ext4 partition, and now I'm trying to copy everything back.  I'm using `rsync -a --info=progress2` for most of the copy operations.

My problem is that after 100 GB or so, I tend to get weird errors:

```
rsync: write failed on "somepath": Read-only file system (30)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(389) [receiver=3.1.0]
```

If I try to list the directory that rsync was working on when it failed, I see weird results:

```
drwx------  3 pdaddy pdaddy 4096 Aug 28 2011 subdirectory1
drwx------  3 pdaddy pdaddy 4096 Mar 12 2014 subdirectory2
d?????????  ? ?      ?         ?           ? subdirectory3
d?????????  ? ?      ?         ?           ? subdirectory4
```

Trying to list the directories with question marks in their listings, and even some of them without, gives me:

```
ls: reading directory subdirectory3: Input/output error
total 0
```

Even fdisk has errors:

```
~ % fdisk /dev/sde   
fdisk: unable to read /dev/sde: Input/output error
```

If I try to unmount the drive, the `umount` command hangs.  I ran `htop` and saw that umount was using 100% of one CPU core.  I assumed it was committing journals or some such, so I let it go all night once, but it was in the same state in the morning.  Issuing `sudo reboot` or `sudo init 6` while `umount` is hung results in yet another hung terminal.  I have to hold the power button.  Just now I tried rebooting without explicitly unmounting, and it hung with a black screen (the monitor went to sleep), and no response via ssh or the keyboard.

After a hard power cycle, I unmounted the disk and did `sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sde1`, and there were no errors.  I checked the files, and they seemed to all be there and a sample of them were correct.

I assumed the errors had something to do with the journal being too large (maybe it's limited to a maximum size?), so I remounted with `-o data=writeback`.  I figured it's a good idea anyway to mount this way temporarily while restoring terabytes worth of files.

This helped to marginally speed the copy, but did not help with the errors.  Twice more, I've gotten into the same state.  A hard power cycle is the only thing I can do, and afterward, a disk check shows no errors, the files seem okay, and I can copy another 100 GB or so.

What's going on?  I think the disk itself is healthy.  I had no problems with it before reformatting.  Should I do a sector scan on the disk?  It's 5 TB, so I'm hesitant to do that.

---

I've restored some more files, watching the kernel logs, as suggested by Stephen Kitt.  Before `rsync` failed, I started seeing some funky errors:

```
[ 8807.572286] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x7fffffff SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[ 8807.572290] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 8807.572293] ata4.00: cmd 61/40:00:c0:57:b6/05:00:b7:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 688128 out
[ 8807.572293]          res 40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[ 8807.572295] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
```

The last three messages repeat many times, then I get:

```
[ 8807.572412] ata4: hard resetting link
[ 8808.060464] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 8808.062462] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 8808.076459] ata4.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
```

The last message repeats 20 times or so, and then I get:

```
[ 8808.076526] ata4: EH complete
```

47 seconds later, the sequence repeats itself.  And again 81 seconds after that, and 120 seconds after that, except this time, it starts with:

```
[ 9160.779935] ata4.00: NCQ disabled due to excessive errors
```

The next time, it's different.  It starts the same, but then I see:

```
[ 9235.819291] ata4: hard resetting link
[ 9241.181501] ata4: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[ 9245.839449] ata4: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
```

This repeats a couple of times, and then:

```
[ 9290.922301] ata4: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[ 9290.922303] ata4: hard resetting link
[ 9295.948393] ata4: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[ 9295.948400] ata4: reset failed, giving up
[ 9295.948401] ata4.00: disabled
```

There are some new errors:

```
[ 9295.948522] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdf] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 9295.948524] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdf] CDB: 
[ 9295.948525] Write(16): 8a 00 00 00 00 00 b9 0c fd 00 00 00 40 00 00 00
[ 9295.948538] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 3104636160
[ 9295.948542] EXT4-fs warning (device sdf1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 49807774 (offset 155189248 size 4194304 starting block 388079688)
[ 9295.948543] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 388079264
```

(Note that I've shuffled some drives since I started this post, and this drive is now sdf instead of sde.)

This last error repeats several times with different logical blocks, and then I get this an equal number of times:

```
[ 9295.948585] EXT4-fs warning (device sdf1): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 49807774 (offset 155189248 size 4194304 starting block 388079856)
```

There's more of the same, and all the while the copy is still going on without complaining.  Finally I get:

```
[ 9295.950321] Aborting journal on device sdf1-8.
[ 9295.950345] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 610304000, lost sync page write
[ 9295.950361] EXT4-fs (sdf1): Delayed block allocation failed for inode 49807775 at logical offset 0 with max blocks 1024 with error 30
[ 9295.950362] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 9295.950365] EXT4-fs (sdf1): This should not happen!! Data will be lost
[ 9295.950365] 
[ 9295.950366] EXT4-fs error (device sdf1) in ext4_writepages:2421: Journal has aborted
[ 9295.950368] EXT4-fs error (device sdf1): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[ 9295.950370] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdf1-8.
[ 9295.950371] EXT4-fs (sdf1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[ 9295.950372] EXT4-fs (sdf1): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[ 9295.950379] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 9295.950394] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 9326.009002] scsi_io_completion: 10 callbacks suppressed
[ 9326.009007] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdf] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 9326.009009] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdf] CDB: 
[ 9326.009011] Write(16): 8a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0f b8 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 9326.009018] blk_update_request: 10 callbacks suppressed
[ 9326.009020] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 4024
[ 9326.009023] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 247, lost async page write
```

(Note that this time I did not unmount and remount with data=writeback, so it was doing its default journaling.)

After this, the rsync failed, presumably because the file system was remounted read-only.

I'm sorry for the log dump.  I've tried to pare it down to the essentials, but I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with what's going on here to pare it down any further.

Comment: Going on a whim here but if the number of files that you are copying via `rsync` is very high, your disk may be having hard time catching up to the write requests. Is it possible for you to divide up the files in to smaller chunks and run several `rsync` commands, one after finishing another ? Maybe per directory or subdirectory level ?

Comment: are there filesystems mounted under the mountpoint of /dev/sde1 that *are* read-only? cd-rom, /proc, etc?

Comment: @MelBurslan:  Is the state of Linux's buffered I/O really so bad that one can overflow the buffers that easily and cause such a catastrophic failure like this?

Comment: @JeffSchaller:  No, this disk is mounted in a directory beneath the root, and nothing else is mounted inside of it.

Comment: @PDaddy I'm not sure where Mel got his theory, but there's no reason for slow drives to cause failures. Does `dmesg` show any drive errors?

Comment: @StephenKitt:  Let me find out.  I'm watching dmesg now, I'll start restoring some more files and wait for it to error again.

Comment: @PDaddy I don't think so, but again, it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: @StephenKitt: It happened pretty quickly this time.  I've added log messages (a lot of them, sorry), to the question.

Comment: BTW there's no need to apologise as far as I'm concerned; it's better to have too much information than too little!

Comment: what brand and model of external drive was it?  some manufacturers do weird things to the firmware of external drives that make them difficult or impossible to use as a normal drive (i.e. not in their external case).  WD is notorious for making such drives.

Comment: @cas:  It's a Seagate STBV5000100.  It was a little difficult to use it as an internal drive because like most large external drives these days, the USB adapter card does 4Kn emulation on top of the 512e that the drive's board does.  Sheez.  So when I installed in internally, I adjusted the entries in the partition table and in the BPB of the NTFS boot sector to account for the change in sector size, and then the drive worked fine.  But I wanted a clean format (I was a little nervous about having performed this surgery), and I wanted a native Linux file system.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if the 512e thing could have something to do with my problem.  I''m afraid I don't understand ext4 well enough to know what the allocation size is on my partition (like cluster size on NTFS), and I'm not sure if the allocation units are aligned with the 4K sectors.  I wonder if I'm doing a whole lot of misaligned writes and the drive is going crazy over it.  Maybe I'll figure out how to enable 4Kn and reformat again.

Comment: Oh, looks like I'm stuck with 512e: http://serverfault.com/questions/593742/upgrading-raid-controller-to-4kn-do-i-have-to-reinitialize-the-array-to-use-4k

Comment: But my partition starts on sector 2048, and my block size is 4096, so I don't think alignment is my problem.

Comment: Stupid question: any chance that the source medium is corrupt?  Basic quick fsck would reveal any surprises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a hardware issue, rather than a kernel bug. You can try the following:

- re-seat the SATA cable
- use another SATA cable
- run SMART diagnostics (the self-tests, see `smartmontools`)
- run a destructive `badblocks` scan

If you have a spare drive or computer you could also try switching (use another drive in the same computer, use the troublesome drive in another computer) to check whether the motherboard's at fault. Since the drive seems to have issues under load a simple `dd if=/dev/zero of=...` with appropriate size parameters might be enough to reproduce the errors.

I'm not sure if your drive's warranty would apply since it was originally an external drive...

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into hardware issues.  You're right that I was able to reproduce the problem by `dd`ing /dev/zero to the drive.  I got 32 GB written before it failed the same way.  I ran `smartctl -a` beforehand, and Raw_Read_Error_Rate, Spin_Up_Time, Reallocated_Sector_Ct, Seek_Error_Rate, and Spin_Retry_Count were all in pre-fail state.  I'm going to try to see if power might be an issue, since I have 4 internal and 2 external drives and this computer has a modest power supply at best, and this drive, being 3.5" and probably having multiple platters, is likely quite electron thirsty.

Comment: Preliminary results look like power is indeed the issue.  Thanks for pointing me down this path.  I'm going to mess with it some more over the next couple of days, and I will likely come back and accept your answer.

Comment: To reduce power draw, I eliminated the two external drives and one internal one.  I don't have an alternate power source right now.  My initial tests with /dev/zero looked positive, but after resuming file restoration, I began seeing errors again.  I'm still tracking down the issue with the drive (I'm convinced it's an issue with the drive now).

Comment: I'd actually be surprised if it was power – spinning drives take most power when the spin up, not when they're running, so systems with power issues generally show problems at boot up; once it's spinning, it takes very little extra power for a drive to write data and the power requirement doesn't increase with the amount of data to be written. Of course hardware is always surprising (when you're familiar with software ;-) so you can't assume it's not power-related, but it's more likely to be something else.

Comment: Well, you're right.  Power adjustments haven't fixed it, and unfortunately, neither has relocation (different data and power cables, different SATA port, different bay with potentially different cooling characteristics).  I successfully wrote 75,000 small files (~5 MB), but failed three minutes into trying to write a large file (~35 GB).  That seems to be the trigger, I think, larger files.  I have no idea why that would be.

Comment: The drive has answered all remaining questions by failing catastrophically.  :'-(

Comment: At least you had all your data elsewhere...

Comment: Not quite.  The restore was coming from multiple smaller drives, and the two I restored from first have already been repurposed, since I had no reason to suspect failure early on.  And that was some of the most important stuff, of course.

Comment: Oh dear, I thought "I copied everything I wanted to keep onto other drives" was good enough :-(.